# Change border Input when typing Angular [ngClass] - [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, validation, input, data-binding

Is it possible to change the input border when it is being written and to show the red border if it has an error or green if it is correct?

In other words, I change the color and the validation when I am inside the input (focus)

**Html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<input type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="name" 
       [ngClass]="{'correct': name.length > 0,'error': name.length === 0}"
>
```

**Css**

```
.correct {
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Typescript**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7an3od?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need change also the outline to 0, and change the box-shadow in focus

```
.correct {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}
.error
{
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;

}
input.correct:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15rem rgba(97, 143, 28,0.25);
}
input.error:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.25)
}
```